# How to create power automate flow where multi select question from MS Form is null/blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, if-condition

I have an issue with my power automate flow, where I need to feed data from a MS form with mult select answers and feed it into a sharepoint list.

[image]

The null is working, when I don't select any of the options, nothing is added, this is working properly.

Although, this is creating a duplicate record in my SharePoint list if I do select any option(s).

[image]

Any idea what's wrong ?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: can you show us a screenshot of your Form ?

Comment: second, in your flow history, is your flow triggered twice ?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the form. In my flow history, the flow is only triggered once.

Comment: Can anyone help, I've really been struggling on getting this to work. Thank you.

Comment: yes i can, drop a screenshot of your Flow history